# Oracle - Find rows in a table where they are similar to rows in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a batch job in Oracle that is designed to match duplicate clients and give them the same ID. I have this bit written and it appears to be working well.

I am now trying to identify records in the table that should have potentially also got matched.

I have created a temp table extracting the records that have been matched together:

```
CREATE TABLE UAT8_MultipleQSID_MatchResults_20230801 AS (
select CAST(NULL AS NUMBER)  NEW_QSCLIENT_ID, cd.*
  from scv_client_details cd
 where cd.qsclient_id in
       (select distinct cd1.qsclient_id
          from scv_client_details cd1
         where cd1.match_details like 'Matched with multiple QSIDs%'));
```

What I would like to now get is any records in **SCV_CLIENT_DETAILS** where the **SEX** is the same, **DOB** is the same and **SURNAME** is like what is already in **UAT8_MultipleQSID_MatchResults_20230801** but the record isn't already in the table above.

I'm not sure how to write this, any ideas?

I tried to write something like this but it is not giving me what I need:

```
select *
  from scv_client_details cd
 where not exists (select *
          from UAT8_MULTIPLEQSID_MATCHRESULTS_20230801 mr
         where cd.sex = mr.sex
           and cd.dob = mr.dob
           and cd.surname like mr.surname
           and cd.system_client_id <> mr.system_client_id)
order by cd.qsclient_id;
```

Thanks,
Mac

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired output. You need to replace `in` with `exists` and add these conditions in the correlated query `... and cd1.qsclient_id = cd.qsclient_id and cd1.sex = cd.sex and cd1.dob = cd.dob and cd1.surname like '%' || cd.surname || '%'` or whatever match condition you need

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to change what is already in the table UAT8_MULTIPLEQSID_MATCHRESULTS_20230801. I would like to try and find data in the table SCV_CLIENT_DETAILS where the data probably should have been matched together... I will need to try and generate data, this is customer sensitive data that I couldn't add here...

Answer (score 1):

I guess that sex and date of birth aren't questionable; we don't know your data so *perhaps* you should apply e.g. `upper` function to sex or `trunc` to `dob`.

However, surname is another story. This is almost certainly wrong:

```
and cd.surname like mr.surname
```

because the way you put it, it is just the same as if you used `cd_surname = mr.surname`. There are several options you can try; here are some of them.

Sample table (I'm comparing two surnames in the same table; you'd compare them in different tables, of course).

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID SURNAME_1  SURNAME_2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Donkey     Key
         2 Foot       Feet
         3 King       Kong
         4 Scott      Scott
```

**Option 1**: `like` operator with wildcards:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test
  3  where upper(surname_1) like '%' || upper(surname_2) || '%';

        ID SURNAME_1  SURNAME_2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Donkey     Key
         4 Scott      Scott

SQL>
```

**Option 2**: `soundex` function:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test
  3  where soundex(surname_1) = soundex(surname_2);

        ID SURNAME_1  SURNAME_2
---------- ---------- ----------
         2 Foot       Feet
         3 King       Kong
         4 Scott      Scott
```

**Option 3**: `instr` function:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test
  3  where instr(upper(surname_1), upper(surname_2)) > 0;

        ID SURNAME_1  SURNAME_2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Donkey     Key
         4 Scott      Scott
```

**Option 4**: similarity:

```
SQL> select t.*,
  2    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(surname_1, surname_2) sim
  3  from test t;

        ID SURNAME_1  SURNAME_2         SIM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Donkey     Key                 0
         2 Foot       Feet               70
         3 King       Kong               85
         4 Scott      Scott             100
```

Now that you know how similar two values are, set the threshold to value you find appropriate, e.g. 90%:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test
  3  where utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(surname_1, surname_2) > 90;

        ID SURNAME_1  SURNAME_2
---------- ---------- ----------
         4 Scott      Scott

SQL>
```